# Launch4j EXE cannot find Annotated Classes in embedded JAR

Tags: java, annotations, exe, executable-jar, launch4j

I am using Launch4j to create an EXE from a JAR.

The JAR file works fine when run with `java -jar jarfile.jar`.

However, when I run the executable, I run into problems.

The code looks for classes with a specific annotation using [AnnotationDetector](https://github.com/rmuller/infomas-asl/tree/master/annotation-detector). I'm debugging through it and I find that `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` returns `jar:file:/C:/Windows/Temp/executable.exe!/com/package/of/annotated/classes/`.

When I try to look through the JAR file "`file:/C:/Windows/Temp/executable.exe!`", it doesn't find my classes because it's assuming that the segment after `jar:`, namely `jar:file:/C:/Windows/Temp/executable.exe!`, is a JAR, but it is not.

Why is the resource URL being generated as that?

OR

How can I navigate through the EXE as I would have the JAR?

OR

How can I fix it so that my classes are found?

I'm looking for any help I can get. However, I'd like to not hardcode the classes into a static list, but rather to allow runtime discovery.

Thanks!